# googlemapsのポリゴンのset_atイベントについて

Tags: javascript, google-maps

複数パスを持つポリゴンの変形イベントが取得できません。

```
// ポリゴンの作成
var path1 = [　// 外側ポリゴン
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(36.66841891894785,138.636474609375),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(36.90597988519295,139.3780517578125),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(36.756490329505176,139.7076416015625),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(36.38149043210595,140.0701904296875),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(35.92019610057511,140.020751953125),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(35.60371874069731,139.59228515625),
];
var path2 = [　// 内側ポリゴン
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(36.421282443649496,139.19677734375),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(36.06686213257888,138.8671875),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(35.817813158696616,139.1748046875),
　　　　new google.maps.LatLng(35.71083783530009,139.98779296875)
];
var polygonOptions = {
　　　　paths: [path1, path2],
　　　　geodesic: true,
　　　　editable: true,
　　　　clickable:true
};
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(polygonOptions);

// 変形イベント取得
var polygonPaths = polygon.getPaths();
for(var i=0;i<=polygonPaths.length-1;i++){
　　　　google.maps.event.addListener(value, 'set_at', function(){
       　　　　console.log("aa");
  　　　 });
}
```

polygon.getPath()で取得したパスにイベント付与をすると
外側ポリゴンの変形イベントはキャッチできました。

Answer (score 1):

ご提示のコードには`value`の定義がありませんが、おそらくこの`value`を取得する部分で躓いているのでしょう。

`Polygon.prototype.getPaths()`の戻り値は`MVCArray`オブジェクトです。
単なる配列ではないので`polygonPaths[i]`のように添字でアクセスすることはできません。
for文内で`MVCArray.prototype.getAt()`メソッドを呼ぶか、`MVCArray.prototype.forEach()`メソッドを利用してください。

```
var polygonPaths = polygon.getPaths();
for(var i = 0; i < polygonPaths.length; i++){
  var polygonPath = polygonPaths.getAt(i);
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygonPath, 'set_at', function(){
    console.log("aa");
  });

  /* 下記のようにも書けます。
  polygonPath.addListener('set_at', function(){
    console.log("aa");
  });
  */
}
```

またはこっち

```
var polygonPaths = polygon.getPaths();
polygonPaths.forEach(function(polygonPath) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygonPath, 'set_at', function(){
    console.log("aa");
  });
});
```